# spark word2vec window size

Tags: machine-learning, apache-spark, word2vec

Is there anyway to change the window size used in `pyspark.mllib.feature.Word2Vec` or is it permanently fixed at 5?  This seems like a fairly important feature.

I don't see the option here:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.Word2Vec

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thats correct, looking at the Word2Vec code we can see that it is a private val. If you wanted to you could maybe override Word2Vec to change the window size. I've created a JIRA ( https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10299 ) to allow the window size to be set, since 1.5 is already in the RC phase this probably won't make it in until 1.6 time.

Comment: As a follow up, I added a `windowSize` parameter you can now use to control the window size in 1.6 + :)